# Data splitting using kennard stone

Tags: machine-learning

I would like to use kennard stone algorithm for splitting a dataset into training and test set. Does Weka /Rapidminer/any free software with GUI has a feature to do this? If so, would like to know the steps to perform this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use R and package `soil.spec`.

Function is :

```
# Sample selection based on the Kennard-Stone algorithm
ken.sto(inp, per = "T", per.n = 0.3, num, va = "F", sav = "T", path = "", out = "Sel")
```

here is the document: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/soil.spec/soil.spec.pdf

see page 8 for `ken.sto` function. To see an example of using this function you can use `example(ken.sto)` or just read the manual (link above).